# Find and Replace in SQLite being mucked up by percent sign

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I'm trying to use this code:

```
UPDATE media_items SET content_url = replace(content_url,’cd%20images’,'my%20music’);
```

And I *know* that the percent signs are mucking it up, and I have to use some sort of escape to get them to read properly, but I've done a bunch of searching, and anything I find doesn't seem to work.  What is the proper syntax to include an escape for the percent signs to get it to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you just double them: `replace(content_url, "cd%%20images", "my%%20music")`.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, and also fixed my comma placement (you can't tell but I forgot to put spaces after the commas) and now it's error free, but it doesn't seem to be updating the table properly.

Comment: I'd have to see the contents of the table before and after to make any guesses about what's still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE parent_path = ? OR parent_path LIKE ? ESCAPE '\'
```

then for query parameter to use for like, replace all % with \% and _ with \_ in parameter value